# Repeating Dataset from API response in Wix Code

Tags: velo

How can I repeat the display of response from API in Wix?

I have the following code in my backend module that queries the API for data like so:

```
export function getTopCoins() {
const url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10';

return fetch(url, {method: 'get'})
    .then(response => response.json());
}
```

and then in the frontend, I want to render it in the browser like so:

```
export function page1_viewportEnter(event, $w) {
     getTopCoins().then(response => {
        response.forEach(($w, itemData, index) => {
            $w('#coinList').text = itemData.name;
        });
     });
}
```

So basically I have a Paragraph element with the ID of name coinList. So as you can see I want to display a list of names of the top 10 coins from coin market cap. How can I achieve this?

A working version of this was one that displayed the name of the first item on the list, this is the code:

```
export function page1_viewportEnter(event, $w) {
     getTopCoins().then(response => {
        $w('#coinList').text = "Name: " + response[0].name + "\n";
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the (pretty new) feature of Wix called **Repeaters**. Its in a Beta phase at the moment. You may find it under Add Panel --> Lists & Grids...

Then, in Wix Code IDE, you may write something like that (assuming you connected all the proper data binding with the *connect panel* configuration between you `dataset` and the `repeater` component:

```js
export function page1_viewportEnter(event, $w) {
 getTopCoins().then(response => {
    $w('#repeater1').data = response;
 });
}
```

You may refer to the [Repeater API](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/$w.Repeater.html) here.

One more thing, if I'm allowed to suggest: if you don't have any backend logic when calling `getTopCoins` from your backend code, you may use [Wix Fetch API](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html) in you frontend code directly and save a network hop (faster and better performance)

Enjoy!

Comment: Yea I finally used it but I'm quite sure I didn't use it right. 
Here's the final output - https://adewolemayowa.wixsite.com/cryptolive

Also, please check out the concept with which I used the repeater - https://www.dunebook.com/create-a-cryptocurrency-price-update-website-using-wix-code/

instead of repeating the repeaters I believe there should be a way to do it dynamically as you mentioned above. 

How do I apply the texts for each repeater in a better way?

Comment: regarding your latest question, you may populate your dataset with the response, and use the databinding configuration to bind each item in the repeater to a field in you collection. Once the dataset data will be updated - it will update the repeater component (and subcomponents) as well

Comment: How do I use it in this context then? This data binding configuration is not documented anywhere in the API docs. I want to improve that tutorial and show that it's possible to do it dynamically. Please, Could you share a snippet? Maybe by populating one or 2 text element and image in the repeater?
You can post another answer to better highlight the code. Thank you.

Comment: oh... I thought to use `dataset.setFieldValues` but I see now that it is for only the current item. Anyway, binding a repeater's inner components is being done like any other component binding as seen in WixCode tutorials. Probably the code above is the best practice way to render what you desired.
Also check [onItemReady](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/$w.Repeater.html#onItemReady)